# Unable to read an xls (a password protected file) after decrypting it

Tags: python, dataframe, xls, password-protection

```
decrypted_workbook = io.BytesIO()
with open(file_path, 'rb') as file:
    office_file = msoffcrypto.OfficeFile(file)
    office_file.load_key(password=password)
    office_file.decrypt(decrypted_workbook)

df = pd.read_excel(decrypted_workbook)
```

I have a password protected xls file which I tried decrypting using msoffcrypto.OfficeFile().
Now when I tried to read the decrypted file, it gives me the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 52-53: illegal UTF-16 surrogate
```

I was expecting to read the decrypted file as a workbook. I tried specifying

```
df = pd.read_excel(decrypted_workbook)
```

```
df = pd.read_excel(decrypted_workbook,encoding = "utf-8")
```

I also tried

```
df = pd.read_excel(decrypted_workbook, encoding = "utf-16")
```

None of them worked

Comment: Are you sure the password is correct? Can you open the file? If the password is wrong, decryption will produce invalid files, not throw an error. A hard-coded encoding will only *cause* problems. `xlsx`, the actual Excel format since 2006, is a ZIP package containing XML files using Unicode.

Comment: Also tried it without hard coded encoding. Still getting the same thing

Comment: Probably because the password is wrong. Can you open the file in the first place?

Comment: You can use `msoffcrypto` as a command line tool to decrypt a password protected Excel file. Can you decrypt the file with the password you have?

Comment: The password is right. I checked. When I do decrypted_workbook.getvalue() I'm getting b'\xd0\xcf\x11\xe0\xa1\xb1\x1a\

As the first few lines

Comment: Excel files are binary files so that doesn't mean anything. Did you try using `msoffcrypto-tool` to decrypt the Excel file? If the password is good, the library may have a problem. The bytes don't look like a ZIP file, which means you're trying to use the obsolete `xls` format. ZIP files start with `PK`.  Have you tried with a proper `xlsx` file?

Comment: I'm actually new to this. I don't really have the option of converting the xls into an xlsx file and then read it as there are too many files like these to read. I didn't get what you meant by the zip files part. Can you an example by writing a few lines of code. And thanks a lot for spending so much time on this

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
import msoffcrypto
import io
import pandas as pd

decrypted = io.BytesIO()

with open("test_encrypted.xlsx", "rb") as f: # replace with actual file path
    file = msoffcrypto.OfficeFile(f)
    file.load_key(password="test")  # Use password
    try:
        file.decrypt(decrypted)
        # Create an ExcelFile object
        xls_file = pd.ExcelFile(decrypted)

        # Print sheet names to verify
        print(xls_file.sheet_names)

    except msoffcrypto.exceptions.InvalidKeyError:
        print('The password is incorrect..')
```

If still it does not work, then the file could potentially be corrupted.

Comment: I'm still getting the following error:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 52-53: illegal UTF-16 surrogate

Comment: Could it be that something is wrong with your file itself

Comment: I can't see what's wrong with it. It opens properly when i open it in excel